# glDrawElements/Arrays not working

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, lwjgl3

Given the following [OpenGL call stack](https://hastebin.com/raw/foyilelako).

According to my knowlegde, the calls to glDrawElements/Arrays are ok.(?)

But, they do not draw anything. (There is no triangle)
The calls to glBegin() and glVertex() works fine.

Full source: [here](https://github.com/stelar7/engine/tree/master/src/main/java/no/stelar7/engine)

Comment: I don't see you setting the uniform "scale" in the `gDraw*` versions.

Comment: The scale is set in the update() method. I removed it from the call stack paste, but I'll add it back in. The shaders affect the glBegin call aswell, so they should look the same.

Comment: I recommend using [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/) to capture a frame and to find out what's really being sent to the GPU. There are way too many variables at play here.

Comment: @Dan the values i read from RenderDoc seem to be totaly wrong..  The IBO is all 3722304989, and the VBO is all -1.9984e+18.. Tho i might be using it wrong? [link to .rdc file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5hj7as9xd491qo/log.rdc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out LWJGL does not allow the use of .wrap() to create a FloatBuffer?
Use BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(), then put() and flip().

Ive created an [issue](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/289) on their github to see the answer

Answer (score 0):

At https://github.com/stelar7/engine/blob/master/src/main/java/no/stelar7/engine/rendering/buffers/VertexBufferObject.java#L54 you have:

```
glBufferData(type, data, draw);
```

And likewise at your other glBufferData call.

These are not legal glBufferData calls; please see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml

```
void glBufferData( GLenum target,
                   GLsizeiptr size,
                   const GLvoid * data,
                   GLenum usage);
```

As you'll see, glBufferData actually has 4 parameters, with the second one - `GLsizeiptr size` - being the one that is missing from your calls.  It's also important that this is the size of the `data` parameter in bytes, and *not* the number of items in an array.

Comment: This is using LWJGL3s wrapper around OpenGL, and its a legal call there.
link to docs: https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glBufferData-int-java.nio.FloatBuffer-int-

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the element array before you draw something with it. It's not a problem now, because you only have a single element buffer, but if you want to draw multiple meshes, it's necessary.

You don't actually need to disable anything, it only introduces unnecessary function calls.

Comment: 1. Deleting/detaching shaders after linking is fine. (The shader works fine on glBegin() calls) 2. The element buffer is linked to the vbo when its set. 3. I enable attrib 0, and put the buffer into it.

Comment: @stelar but then you enable attrib 1 when you render

Comment: Where do you see that? I cant find that in the source, nor the gl call stack i linked?

Comment: @stelar also, are you sure you have OpenGL 3.0+?

Comment: @stelar Sorry, I misread that part

Comment: I set the version to 3.3 Core in the EngineRunner.java:74, it wont go past that point if it doesnt support it. (3.3.0 NVIDIA 375.70)